# How to set proportional Canvas.Left?

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

Is there the way to set the distance between the left side of a control and the left side of its parent Canvas proportionally, not as a fixed value?

I use Canvas (actually DragCanvas, because I allow for the user to drag controls in the canvas). I'm binding values in xaml:

```
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource TableButton}" Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=YTransl}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=XTransl}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
                <j:DragCanvas Margin="10"/>                  
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The problem that the controls which are inside of canvas for bigger screen size, are outside of view for smaller screen size.

I need to set the value "YTransl" and "XTransl" as percentage of the whole canvas, proportionally to the screen size.

Something like `<RowDefinition Height="1*" />` in Grid container.
Or multiplying by screen width and height... I don't know if it is good idea..

Is there the way to do it in xaml? Or I should calculate this in cs and bind the prepared value in xaml?

Comment: You have them bound to properties, so you're halfway there already. Get the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the Canvas, too, and just calculate `XTransl` and `YTransl` accordingly.

Comment: yes... Actual Size of Canvas sounds good. I will try. Thank you